# Show hidden rows in openpyxl line chart

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have already created a LineChart with openpyxl 2.3.2 and saved it to Excel. All went fine.
But all values are always shown even though the base data has been filtered (which is the behavior that I want).

I only found one entry in the openpyxl changelog "#828 Include hidden cells in charts`" but without any further explanation.

Manually the option can be changed later in Excel through selecting the chart --> Data selection --> hidden and empty cells --> uncheck "show data in hidden rows and columns" (translation might not be perfect)

Has anybody of you been able to create a chart with openpyxl and let it reacted to a filtered input?